# trying to get a positive integer output from a while loop with console.hasNextInt

Tags: java, while-loop

```
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("type your age: ");
    while(!console.hasNextInt()|| console.nextInt() <= 0){
        System.out.print("enter a valid age: ");
        console.next();
    }
    int age = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println(age);
```

when only using !console.hasNextInt(), it was able to print an integer. After adding console.nextInt() <= 0 and trying to get a positive number, weird things happened. Can anyone tell me where is wrong here and how I can fix this problem in this while loop? Thx.

Comment: Have you read what each of those methods does? (javadoc)

Comment: Not weird.. Expected things happen :). Take @SotiriosDelimanolis 's advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is discarding the user input to check if it's in the valid range. I believe you'll find the easiest answer is to default to an invalid input and continue checking until the input is valid. So, something like -

```
int age = -1;
while (age < 0) {
    System.out.print("enter a valid age: ");
    if (console.hasNextInt()) {
        age = console.nextInt();
    } else if (console.hasNext()) {        
        console.next();
    } else {
        System.err.println("Console closed. Exiting.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Wlliott Frisch. I am learning Java on my own and trying to figure out how things like hasNextInt and nextInt work in while loop.